# I need help to generate a Grouped and Tabulated report from MySQL Database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'd appreciate if anyone can help me with this; I have spent days trying to get a solution.
I have a MySQL database with several tables; I wish to display a formatted report based on certain queries that affect these tables.

One Query extracts details of records of All Districts in my Database; details of Districts include District Code, Location, District Ministers, Phone and Email. While the other Query extracts details of records of All Zones in my Database,; details of Zones include District Code, Zone Code, Zone Name, Zone Minister. Each District is made up of one or more Zones.

My report is to have headings of District Codes, details of the District and then a listing of the Zones in that District with their details.

```
$districts = all_districts_details();  // The function that returns the Districts as an array
$zones = all_zones_details();  // The function that returns the Zones as an array
```

My code is

```
<?php include '../view/report_header.php'; ?>
    <?php 
    foreach ($districts as $district) {    ?>            
        <table width="1000" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <td id="header5" colspan="2" rowspan="2"><?php echo $district['districtCode']; ?><br><div id="header2"><?php echo '(' . $district['locationName'] . ')'; ?></div></td>
            <td id="header3" width="74">DM</td>
            <td id="header3" width="294"><?php echo 'Pst. ' . $district['othernameDM'] . ' ' . $district['surnameDM']; ?></td>
            <td id="header4" width="177"><?php echo $district['emailDM']; ?></td>
            <td id="header2" width="143"><?php echo $district['phoneDM1']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="header3">ADM</td>
            <td id="header3"><?php echo $district['titleADM'] . '. ' . $district['othernameADM'] . ' ' . $district['surnameADM']; ?></td>
            <td id="header4"><?php echo $district['emailADM']; ?></td>
            <td id="header2"><?php echo $district['phoneADM1']; ?></td>
        </tr>

            <?php   foreach ($zones as $zone) { ?>
                <?php if ($zone['district_districtCode'] == $district['districtCode']) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="header6" width="47"><?php echo $zone['district_districtCode'] . '/' . $zone['zoneCode']; ?></td>
                        <td id="header2" width="225"><?php echo $zone['zoneName']; ?></td>
                        <td id="header3">ZM</td>
                        <td id="header3"><?php echo $zone['titleZM'] . '. ' . $zone['othernameZM'] . ' ' . $zone['surnameZM']; ?></td>
                        <td id="header4"><?php echo $zone['emailZM']; ?></td>
                        <td id="header2"><?php echo $zone['phoneZM1']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php }?>
            <?php } ?>


        </table>
 <?php   } ?>

<?php include '../view/report_footer.php'; ?>
```

The code above only displays the Zone details for the First District only and displays the other districts but no Zone details.

Is there something I've done wrong? I want to achieve this without having to use classes. I'd appreciate suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump($zones)` to see if there is actually any zone data to loop over?

Comment: how are you loading the arrays, are you sure the $zones array has the ther data in it?  `print_r($zones);`

Comment: If you read his explanation, he says **code above only displays the Zone details for the First District**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first loop you need either:

- rewind the $zones array to start over. This will display the same zones for the second distict.
- fetch new zones for the second district.

Comment: (JvdBerg, can't mention your name with an @ in front of it?) is right, your pointer has to be reset so you can start iterating it again, have a look at [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php);

Comment: Thanks JvdBerg and dbf, how do I do this? I tried reset as you suggested but gave the same result. Or am I missing the position at which I must use the reset function?

Comment: Thank you guys, I just tried it again and it has worked. I had failed to call the function that returns the zones array again. Thanks a million, I appreciate your help.